# CakePHP 2.2.1 how to pass validationErrors to SetFlash?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm building a simple contact form for my site.

In my model I have:

```
class Contact extends AppModel {
public $useTable = false;
public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Field name must be not empty'
    ),
    'email' => 'email',
    'message' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Field message must be not empty'
    )
);
}
```

Controller:

```
class ContactsController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

public function index() {

}

public function send() {
$this->Contact->set($this->request->data);
if ($this->Contact->validates()) {
//sending mail logic
        };
                                } else {
// didn't validate logic
$errors = $this->Contact->validationErrors;

}
}
}
}
```

and in index.ctp view I have:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Contact', array('action' => 'send'));
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => 'Your name:'));
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => 'Your e-mail:'));
echo $this->Form->input('message', array('rows' => '6', 'label' => 'Your message:'));
echo $this->Form->end('Send button');

echo $this->Session->flash();
```

So because I use Validating Data from the Controller I have a problem with passing $errors to Session->flash. What is a proper way to do that? I don't want to make additional view for "send" method in my controller.

Comment: try to use a schema for better validation and form helper output: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/15/tools-plugin-part-2-contact-form/

Comment: @mark I don't want to use plugins. Is there any method to achieve my goals without Tools Plugin?

Comment: you dont have to use the plugin. just take out the code you need (copy and paste). also note, that using this schema approach you will also not have to pass down the validationErrors to the view. it will be done automatically. so I'd say it is the cleanest approach here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I don't use second view for the send method in my controller.
When I add a $this->render('index'); it solves all problems and now my form automatically displays validation messages.